# Adding a 3D effect to a layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating a android layout using framelayout and linear vertical layout. 
I am interested to achieve this

[image]

I have created  layout and got this

[image]

Here is the code of the layout file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".testActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
     </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

The reason for using framelayout is because I want to add floating buttons later. 
How can I get the 3D effect on the horizontal linear layout as shown in first image.

Comment: You need to use **[`CardView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView)** for that

Comment: check this artical [Android working with Card View and Recycler View](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Your Solution is here :**

You can use this code to archive your UI

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
                 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                 card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
                 card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                 tools:context=".testActivity">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView15"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="TextView" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Button" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView15"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="TextView" />
                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Button" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView15"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="TextView" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/button2"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="Button" />
                     </LinearLayout>
                   </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, that should be a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)

Now, about those `layouts`, there is `CardView` and [here](https://medium.com/@droidbyme/android-cardview-with-recyclerview-90cfeda6a4d4) is a nice example to combine both RecyclerView & CardView. You can use CardView to achieve that black button from right also, buuut I think you should use `AppCompatButton`

If you need any other help, leave a comment.

Happy coding !

Comment: Thanks, I will check the links

Answer (score 0):

The 3D layout you mean is cardElevation. Just use cared elevation on row you will inflate. That means you either use Recyclerview if you have much data or hard-coded cardView if you have few amount of data on the screen.
The major thing is to use cardElevation property of each dataPoint.